# Insert/Update navigation properties

Tags: entity-framework

I have two classes:

```
public class Product : Base
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Ingredient:Base
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

My question is: What's the best way to insert/update ingredients for a product?
Assuming I need to validate Product and Ingredient before insert/update, should I create one product repository or a product repository and ingredient repository?

---

I saw that it's pretty easy when I use my DbContext inside my controller.. but if I need a system made by modules(bl,dao) ?

Comment: If you are using Entity Framework, I think you should only use repositories if you've got a large layered application. Is that the case?

Comment: This is a repost: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623668/navigation-properties-repository. Please don't. You can always edit your original question to improve it.

Comment: No dude, it's similar but not equal questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decision for number of repositories is based on analysis of aggregate roots in your domain model. If `Product` is aggregate root for `Ingredient` your `Ingredient` instance cannot exist without `Product`.

Is `Product` aggregate root for `Ingredient`? If yes you should handle both products and ingredients in single `ProductRepository` if not you should have separate repository for both entities.

Usual indication that you need two repositories is many-to-many relation but in such case EF entities don't play very nicely with repositories because if you have direct navigation property between `Product` and `Ingredient` you don't have any way to force developer to use second repository for `Ingeredient` access and modification.